# C++ Memory leak error when implementing Stack class

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, stack

I was implementing a Stack class and when I tried to call push(), I received a memory leak error (double free or corruption(fasttop)). 
Here is my code:

```
#include "StackNode.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Stack::Stack(){
  curr = NULL;   
}

Stack::~Stack(){
  while(!empty())
    pop();
  delete curr;
}

bool Stack::empty(){
  return curr==NULL;
}

int Stack::top(){
  return curr->value;
}

void Stack::push(int a){
  StackNode * temp = new StackNode;
  temp->value = a;

  if (!empty())        // atleast 1 element
  temp->prev = curr;   // temp links to current

   curr = temp;        // current becomes temp
}

void Stack::pop(){
  if (!empty()){
  StackNode * temp = curr;
  curr->prev = curr;
  delete temp;
  }
}
```

I debugged and traced it to:

```
   temp = curr;
```

I cannot see any other way of implementing the push() method. My StackNode only contains a default constructor which sets the pointer **prev** to **NULL**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here is my StackNode:

```
#include "StackNode.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

StackNode::StackNode(){
   prev = NULL;
}
```

And here is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
  //  Stack s;
    s.push(1);
  // cout<<s.top()<<endl;
  cout<<"pass"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With what you've shown a "double free error" can be caused with a simple 2 or 3 line program.  `{Stack s; s.push(10); Stack s2 = s;}`.  Read up on the rule of 3.

Comment: Also, you need to show your `main` program, not just your class.  It is how you're using the class that counts, and as I've shown, it is simple to make your `Stack` class have issues.

Comment: Well, so far, I was using main to test my class. So I only have:
Stack s; s.push(1);

Comment: Oh, and I won't be needing copy constructor or = operator.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We don't know what `StackNode` is.  Also, any class that is written that handles dynamically allocated memory should have a copy constructor and assignment operator.  If not, then it is incomplete and can very easily be broken.  Copying and assigning can occur without you doing it explicitly.

Comment: Alright. Here is my current code. My .h files only define constructors and methods.

Comment: Shouldn 't it be `curr = curr->prev` instead the other way around in `pop`? Your `main` also seems to be in a broken state as you commented out the declaration of `s` and a constructor call is missing

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed that. And yea, I was commenting different parts to try to trace my crash.

Comment: Thank you. pop() was the issue. And I think the memory leak was happened when it automatically called the destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three questions.

1. Stack::pop

   ```
   void Stack::pop(){
       if (!empty()){
       StackNode * temp = curr;
       curr->prev = curr;         // curr = curr->prev ?
       delete temp;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Stack::~Stack

   ```
   Stack::~Stack(){
     while(!empty())
       pop();
     delete curr;                 // Why delete curr here?
   }
   ```
3. Stack::push

   ```
   void Stack::push(int a){
     StackNode * temp = new StackNode;
     temp->value = a;             // temp->prev assign NULL ?

     if (!empty())
       temp->prev = curr;

       curr = temp;
   }
   ```

Comment: 1 and 3: Can you clarify? 2: curr is a pointer that points to the top of the stack. If I don't delete it, the memory it points to won't be freed

Comment: @user2999870 is stack is empty - there should not be any "top" in it.

Comment: @user2999870 1. curr->prev = curr;  the curr would be invalid.  3. If first->prev is not NULL.  It would run into an error when you pop the last element.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I'll probably add an exception/condition on top()

Comment: @DanaYan 1. I want curr to point to curr->prev (pretending that curr->prev is the new top element of the stack). Then, I'm trying to free the space by delete.. Is there a better way to implement pop()?
3. My constructor StackNode() assigns the pointer prev to NULL so I didn't define it here.

Comment: Thank you. pop() was the issue. The memory leak was happening when it called the destructor. I failed to spot that.

Comment: @user2999870 Before you implement some kind of data struct, drawing it on a paper is a good way. : )